# calculate the minimum distance between 2 dataframe and estimate the missing points location in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, distance, euclidean-distance

Estimate dataframe:

| index | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.47 | 0.46 |
| 2 | 0.44 | 0.46 |
| 3 | 0.41 | 0.45 |
| 4 | 0.38 | 0.45 |
| 5 | 0.35 | 0.45 |
| 6 | 0.33 | 0.44 |
| 7 | 0.30 | 0.43 |
| 8 | 0.30 | 0.39 |

real_dataframe:

| index | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.46 | 0.463 |
| 4 | 0.40 | 0.453 |
| 5 | 0.37 | 0.455 |
| 6 | 0.34 | 0.450 |
| 7 | 0.32 | 0.448 |

Goal: calculate the minimum distance  between the estimate and real, and addthe distance to the not matched estimate data points to indicate the missing location in real dataframe

the missing might locates in the middle of dataframe, in this case (2,3 and 8) real_missing equals estimate plus the distance

| index | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0.44 plus d | 0.46 plus D |
| 3 | 0.41 plus d | 0.45 plus D |
| 8 | 0.30 plus d | 0.39 plus D |

Comment: Notice: the minimum distance might be between the different index points of estimate dataframe and real dataframe

Comment: In `0.44 plus d` where is d coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
mindistance = []
mindistance_x = []
mindistance_y = []
l_list = []
for x, y in zip(data_test.x_center,data_test.y_center):
    #x = data_test.x_center[0]
    #y = data_test.y_center[0]
    dist = []
    dist_x = []
    dist_y = []
    for w,z in zip(Estimated.x_center,Estimated.y_center):
        distance = math.sqrt((x - w)**2 + (y - z)**2)
        dist.append(distance)
        dist_x.append(x-w)
        dist_y.append(y-z)
    l = np.argmin(dist)
    l_list.append(l)
    mindistance.append(dist[l])
    mindistance_x.append(dist_x[l])
    mindistance_y.append(dist_y[l])

#average_min_distance = mean(mindistance)
#average_min_distance
```